# Change default keyboard input source

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I have an `Option`-friendly keyboard source used for enabling mnemonics in menus. It is still English language based but is more keyboardist friendly than the default keyboard input source.

I'd actually prefer to either make this other one "usd2" the default. Or short of that to  *delete* the default input source and use this one in its place. Is there any way to do either of those two options?

[image]

Comment: Try asking the ukulele group:    https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for that resource.  The first several approaches described all say something like "Update: this approach does not work on 10.[8|9] anymore"

Comment: I wonder whether an alternative keyboard switcher like Kawa would let you fix the default as you want?   https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @TomGewecke is a good source [Ukelele google group](https://%20groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1) that shows there is likely no way to do this in the half dozen or so recent versions of `macOS`.

The least intrusive approach is likely then :

- switch to the custom input source

[image]

- disable  `Automatically switch to a document's input source` in `Settings | Keyboard`

[image]

I don't know yet how often/under what conditions the `Input Source` will need to be re-selected: I'll update here as we go.

**Update** This method does **NOT** work: the Input Source reverts back to the System Default essentially every time. I'm not sure why it did *not* the first times I tried it - if it had not I would not have made this answer.